# What's a good Protoss unit mix / strategy to bust a large Photon Cannon base defense?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

I was in a FFA with 2 other Protoss and a Terran... towards the end there were a ton of static Photon Cannons guarding bases.  I was thinking Immortals with a few Sentries for Guardian Shield would be best... but I wonder if there are any other tips or unit ideas for cheaply breaking up a giant cannon farm to attack an enemy Protoss' base in PvP

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Colossi with Extended Thermal Lance have a range of 9, while Photon Cannons only have a range of 7. You can snipe off the defenses without taking any damage.

Comment: Remember that taking out the Pylon will disable all the photon cannons :D

Answer (score 3):

The slightly lower tech option is immortals, who do their full 50 damage to buildings while only taking half damage to their shields (20 maxed at 10).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a lot and building up a large, upgraded army is really what it comes down to..... making cannons early or even late can but a Protoss pretty far behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any money and only a squad of stalker, that should work too with blink micro. But usually it is not worth the time investment.